# Getting NULL values for UPPERCASE columns while reading an orc table from Hive (version 2.3.0-amzn-0)

Tags: hive, emr, orc

We are storing some column names in UPPER CASE while generating an ORC file. When we read the ORC file from hive 2.3.0 in EMR, we are getting NULL values for all UPPER-CASE columns. It is working fine in hive2.1.0 and other versions.

Below is the metadata of orc file

```
Type: struct<GRADE:double,LOSAL:double,HISAL:double,purge_seq_id:double,purge_date:timestamp,aj_retention_applied:string,aj_pk_column:double>
```

It is a known issue in Hive 0.13 and got fixed in later versions.

Comment: What sort of help are you looking for? If the issue got fixed in later versions, isn't the answer to upgrade?

Comment: Need to work on hive2.3.0 version. So, Is there any workaround for hive2.3.0?

Comment: If it is a known issue, can you find the ticket on their bug tracker? Add that to your post, if you can find it. From there, you can perhaps ping the maintainers to see if there is a backported fix.